# Wordpress only showing 1 Custom Post Type instead of 2

Tags: php, wordpress, post, types, custom-post-type

I have been trying to add 2 custom post types onto my Wordpress website. Everytime I try to add the second custom post type through my functions.php the first one disappears from the menu. I have tried to find the solution for this problem but most of the stackoverflow threads were talking about the add_action part I already added to the code.

Thanks in advance for helping out!

```
/* Huren CPT */
function custom_post_type() {

  $labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Huren', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Huur', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Huren', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'Huren', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Post Type voor huren', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes' ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( ),
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => '',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
  );
  register_post_type( 'Huren', $args );
}



// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );


/* Leasen CPT */
function custom_post_type2() {

  $labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Leasen', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Lease', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Leasen', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'Leasen', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Post Type voor leasen', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes' ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( ),
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => '',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
  );
  register_post_type( 'Huren', $args );
}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type2', 0 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `custom_post_type2()` function...

Change:

`register_post_type( 'Huren', $args );`

To:

`register_post_type( 'Leasen', $args );`

Comment: Oh man I didn't even notice that! Thanks so much Lumonald, much appreciated!